# Grid with grouped headers/columns (super headers)

Tags: wpf

I would like to achieve something like:

```
               Day 1                  |                Day 2
--------------------------------------| -------------------------------------
Location 1 | Location 2 | Location 3  | Location 1 | Location 2 | Location 3
---------- | ---------- | ----------- | ---------- | ---------- | -----------
           |            |             |            |            |           
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
           |            |             |            |            |           
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
           |            |             |            |            |           
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
           |            |             |            |            |           
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

<strike>I need to display a list of appointments/events for specific days but grouped by locations.</strike>

I want to display days and locations even when there are no events (just empty grid so I can add my own events there).

I'm planning on using `DataGrid` or `ListBox`/`ListView`. Is it a good idea or I should create those headers some other way? Could you point me in the right direction?

This question is just about displaying empty grid(multiple listviews or datagrid with headers generated from list of locations and list of dates):

```
public IObservableCollection<DateTime> DaysToDisplay { get; set; }
public IObservableCollection<string> LocationsToDisplay { get; set; }
```

Comment: What would the point of an empty datagrid be?  It won't do anything, it won't show anything. You're going to need a button or SOMETHING in each cell.

Comment: @Andy Yes, I want to display empty rows/cells in each column - that will map to a list of `TimeSpan`.

Comment: @Andy so when you click on the cell/row it will give you : timespan, location and date.

Comment: There would be a button in the cell then.

Comment: I'm currently using multiple list views in a horizontal stack panel but I need to group it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit confused by your edit saying:

"This question is just about displaying empty grid (generated from list of locations and list of dates)"

Because that directly contradicts:

"I need to display a list of appointments/events for specific days"

But you keep on editing your question and one of those can't be true.

WPF datagrid is best for editing, if that's what you mean by "add my own events there". Although editing directly in a datagrid introduces a lot of edge cases if you are going to validate.

The datagrid doesn't support grouped headers like that.

All solutions you could adopt come with some limitations.

One would be to make the Days template columns.  You  then line up your 3 locations inside them in the one template.

One way of building these repeated columns dynamically:

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/WPF-Dynamic-XAML-Awkward-41b0689f

Another option is 2 datagrids.
The top one only has headers - these being the Days.
The main datagrid is below that and in the same grid, the locations are columns in that.
This works best if the user can't do things like resize and re-order columns.
Re-sizing can be handled by binding the width of the day columns using a converter adds up the width of the corresponding day columns.

An example:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1e414159-70f6-4be3-9be5-56e4f3278366/wpf-multicolumn-super-header?forum=wpf

Comment: I agree I wasn't very clear. Thanks a lot for the answer.